# Send results from one php program to another php program

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a php program that reads excel file and returns the variable perfectly. The variable are as shown below

```
$str  = $jdate . ",";
$str .= $block . ",";
$str .= $a_harv . ",";
$str .= $b_harv . ",";
$str .= $loss . ",";
$str .= $sweet . ",";
$str .= $species . ",";
$str .= $comment . "\n";
```

Now I would to send these variable to another php program(the program sends the variables to data base, it also has no problem) to receive/get the variables as:

```
list($sdate,$block,$a_harv,$b_harv,$loss,$sweet,$species,$comment) = 
explode(",",$_GET['$str']);
```

I wonder how to connect these two programs?

The first is this readExcel_SendResult.php

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');


global $link, $db;

include('db.inc');

include_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php' );
include_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php' );


function endsWith( $str, $suffix ){
  $len = strlen( $suffix );
  return $len == 0 || substr( $str, strlen( $str ) - $len, $len ) === 
$suffix;
}

$excelfilename = 'harv.xlsx';
$excelfilepath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . $excelfilename;

$reader = null;
if( endsWith( $excelfilename, 'xls' ) ){
  $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader( 'Excel5' );
}else if( endsWith( $excelfilename, 'xlsx' ) ){
  $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader( 'Excel2007' );
}

if( $reader ){
  $excel = $reader->load( $excelfilepath );

  $obj1 = $excel->getActiveSheet()->toArray( null, true, true, true );
  $num_row = count($obj1);

  print "Variable Count：" . $num_row . "\n";
  for($i=0; $i<$num_row; $i++){
    $sdate = trim($obj1[$i]['A']);
    if($sdate == "")    continue;
    $block = str_replace(" ","",$obj1[$i]['B']);
    $block = mb_convert_kana($block,"r","utf-8");
    $a_harv = $obj1[$i]['C'];
    $b_harv = $obj1[$i]['D'];
    $loss = $obj1[$i]['E'];
    $sweet = trim($obj1[$i]['F']);
    $species = str_replace(" ","",$obj1[$i]['G']);
    $comment = trim($obj1[$i]['H']);

    list($mm, $dd, $yy) = explode("/",$sdate);
    if($yy == "")   continue;
    $jdate = $yy . "-" . $mm . "-" . $dd;

    $str  = $jdate . ",";
    $str .= $block . ",";
    $str .= $a_harv . ",";
    $str .= $b_harv . ",";
    $str .= $loss . ",";
    $str .= $sweet . ",";
    $str .= $species . ",";
    $str .= $comment . "\n";


    $shell .= "?ARG=" . $str;

  }
}else{
  echo "No reader.";
}
?>
```

The other program I have is this;
send_datatoDB.php

```
global $link, $db;

include'excel_db.php'; 

include('db.inc');

list($sdate,$block,$a_harv,$b_harv,$loss,$sweet,$species,$comment) = 
explode(",",$_GET['$str']);

$block = mb_convert_kana($block,"r","utf-8");

if($species == "type1"){
    $vid = "v2";
} else if ($species == "type2"){
    $vid = "v3";
} else if ($species == "type3"){
    $vid = "v1";
} else {
    $vid = "v4";
}

if(is_numeric($sweet)){
    $sweetness = $sweet;
    $s_and_c = $comment;
} else {
    $sweetness = 0.0;
    $s_and_c = $sweet . $comment;
}


connect_mysql($link, $db);

    $sql = "Select * from tableName where sdate = '{$sdate}' and block = '{$block}' and vid = '{$vid}'";


    $result_id = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    if($result_id == false){
        exit();
    }

    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result_id);
    echo "Result Number：" . $row_cnt . "<br>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_id)) {
                $hid = $row['hid'];
                //echo "hid = " . $hid . "<br>";
    }

    mysqli_close($link);


connect_mysql($link, $db);

    if($row_cnt < 1){       //INSERT
        $values = "'{$sdate}' , '{$block}' , '{$vid}', '{$a_harv}', 
'{$b_harv}', '{$loss}', '{$sweetness}', '{$s_and_c}'";
        $sql = "INSERT into tableNamw ";
        $sql .= "(`sdate`, `block`, `vid`, `A_harv`, `B_harv`, `loss`, 
`sweetness`, `comments`) ";
        $sql .= " VALUES ({$values})";

    //echo $sql;

        $result_id = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        if($result_id == false){
            exit();
        }
    } else {                        //UPDATE
        $sql = "UPDATE tableName SET ";
        $sql .= "a_harv = '" . $a_harv . "', ";
        $sql .= "b_harv = '" . $b_harv . "', ";
        $sql .= "loss = '" . $loss . "', ";
        $sql .= "sweetness = '" . $sweetness . "', ";
        $sql .= "comments = '" . $s_and_c . "'";
        $sql .= " where hid = " . $hid;

       //echo $sql . "<br>";

        $result_id = mysql_query($sql,$link);
        if($result_id == false){
            //echo "<BR>Uooops<BR>";

            exit();
        }
    }

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: I googled "how to connect 2 php programs?" and the first result led to a W3Schools page regarding `include` and `require`. Here is the page: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp. Which is what will solve your problem. Before posting an entire question, you should attempt research it first.

Comment: if you use classes you can just call the other class found on the other page and process the result of your present class there.

Comment: You either `include()`, `require()`, or make use of a `$_POST`. Though I'm really not sure why you need two separate scripts at all. Also, the function `connect_mysql` isn't standard (or referenced in your code), you're mixing MySQL APIs (which will crash your program), and your code is open to SQL injection on top of that, as you don't use parameterised queries.

Comment: Thanks @Obsidian Age for your comment. Managed to make one script but failing to update the Db. Please any help if u can.Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from one page to another page by using **session** and **Cookies**

**Session:**

```
//On page 1
$_SESSION['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];
```

**Cookie:**

```
//One page 1
$_COOKIE['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_COOKIE['varname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a lot of stuff. Instead of making two file put you code in one file and make some changes according to the following code.

Throw all your data from excel to an array by

```
$rec  = array();

$rec['jdate']  = $jdate;
$rec['block'] = $block;
$rec['a_harv'] = $a_harv;
$rec['b_harv'] = $b_harv;
$rec['loss'] = $loss;
$rec['sweet'] = $sweet;
$rec['species'] = $species;
$rec['comment'] = $comment;

$arr[] = $rec;
```

Then

```
if(count($arr) > 0){
    foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
        $row['block'] = mb_convert_kana($row['block'],"r","utf-8");

        if($row['species'] == "type1"){
            $vid = "v2";
        } else if ($row['species'] == "type2"){
            $vid = "v3";
        } else if ($row['species'] == "type3"){
            $vid = "v1";
        } else {
            $vid = "v4";
        }

        if(is_numeric($sweet)){
            $sweetness = $sweet;
            $s_and_c = $comment;
        } else {
            $sweetness = 0.0;
            $s_and_c = $sweet . $comment;
        }
        $sql = "Select * from tableName where sdate = '{$row['sdate']}' and block = '{$row['block']}' and vid = '{$vid}'";


        $result_id = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        if($result_id == false){
            exit();
        }

        $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result_id);
        echo "Result Number：" . $row_cnt . "<br>";

        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_id)) {
            $hid = $r['hid'];
            //echo "hid = " . $hid . "<br>";
        }
        if($row_cnt < 1){       //INSERT
            $values = "'{$row['sdate']}' , '{$row['block']}' , '{$row['vid']}', '{$row['a_harv']}', '{$row['b_harv']}', '{$row['loss']}', '{$row['sweetness']}', '{$row['s_and_c']}'";
            $sql = "INSERT into tableNamw ";
            $sql .= "(`sdate`, `block`, `vid`, `A_harv`, `B_harv`, `loss`, `sweetness`, `comments`) ";
            $sql .= " VALUES ({$values})";

            //echo $sql;

            $result_id = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
            if($result_id == false){
                exit();
            }
        } 
        else {                        //UPDATE
            $sql = "UPDATE tableName SET ";
            $sql .= "a_harv = '" . $row['a_harv'] . "', ";
            $sql .= "b_harv = '" . $row['b_harv'] . "', ";
            $sql .= "loss = '" . $row['loss'] . "', ";
            $sql .= "sweetness = '" . $row['sweetness'] . "', ";
            $sql .= "comments = '" . $row['s_and_c'] . "'";
            $sql .= " where hid = " . $row['hid'];

           //echo $sql . "<br>";

            $result_id = mysql_query($sql,$link);
            if($result_id == false){
                //echo "<BR>Uooops<BR>";

                exit();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very @Kosar Latif. I managed to making some changes and almost done however, the DB doesn't update. Everytime I rerun the program, variables are duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

The edited code is below. I have also include a test mysql database for testing and the data.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
global $link, $db;

include('db2.inc');

include_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php' );
include_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php' );


function endsWith( $str, $suffix ){
  $len = strlen( $suffix );
  return $len == 0 || substr( $str, strlen( $str ) - $len, $len ) === $suffix;
}

$excelfilename = 'harv2.xlsx';
$excelfilepath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . $excelfilename;

$reader = null;
if( endsWith( $excelfilename, 'xls' ) ){
  $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader( 'Excel5' );
}else if( endsWith( $excelfilename, 'xlsx' ) ){
  $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader( 'Excel2007' );
}

if( $reader ){
$excel = $reader->load( $excelfilepath );

  $obj1 = $excel->getActiveSheet()->toArray( null, true, true, true );
  $num_row = count($obj1);

  print "Data Number：" . $num_row . "\n";
  for($i=0; $i<$num_row; $i++){
    $sdate = trim($obj1[$i]['A']);
    if($sdate == "")    continue;
    $block = str_replace(" ","",$obj1[$i]['B']);
    $block = mb_convert_kana($block,"r","utf-8");
    $a_harv = $obj1[$i]['C'];
    $b_harv = $obj1[$i]['D'];
    $loss = $obj1[$i]['E'];
    $sweet = trim($obj1[$i]['F']);
    $species = str_replace(" ","",$obj1[$i]['G']);
    $comment = trim($obj1[$i]['H']);

    list($mm, $dd, $yy) = explode("/",$sdate);
    if($yy == "")   continue;
    $jdate = $yy . "-" . $mm . "-" . $dd;

    $rec  = array();

    $rec['jdate']  = $jdate;
    $rec['block'] = $block;
    $rec['a_harv'] = $a_harv;
    $rec['b_harv'] = $b_harv;
    $rec['loss'] = $loss;
    $rec['sweet'] = $sweet;
    $rec['species'] = $species;
    $rec['comment'] = $comment;

    $arr[] = $rec;

  }
}else{
  echo "No reader.";
}

if(count($arr) > 0){
    foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
        $row['block'] = mb_convert_kana($row['block'],"r","utf-8");

        if($row['species'] == "アイコ"){
            $vid = "v2";
        } else if ($row['species'] == "チャペル"){
            $vid = "v3";
        } else if ($row['species'] == "朱雀"){
            $vid = "v1";
        } else {
            $vid = "v4";
        }
        if($row['sweet']){
            $sweetness = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", '', $row['sweet']) . "\n";
        $s_and_c = $row['comment'];
    } else {
        $sweetness = 0.0;
        $s_and_c = $row['sweetness'] . $row['comment'];
    }
    connect_mysql($link, $db);

        $sql = "Select * from toguchi_harv where sdate = '{$row['sdate']}' and block = '{$row['block']}' and vid = '{$vid}'";

       # echo $sql . "<br>";
        $result_id = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        if($result_id == false){
            exit();
        }

        $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result_id);
        echo "Result Number：" . $row_cnt . "<br>";

        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_id)) {
            $hid = $r['hid'];
            echo "hid = " . $hid . "<br>";
        }

        mysqli_close($link);

    connect_mysql($link, $db);

        if($row_cnt < 1){//INSERT
            $values = "'{$row['jdate']}' , '{$row['block']}' , '{$vid}', '{$row['a_harv']}', '{$row['b_harv']}', '{$row['loss']}', '{$sweetness}', '{$s_and_c}'";

            var_dump($values);

            $sql = "INSERT into toguchi_harv ";
            $sql .= "(`sdate`, `block`, `vid`, `A_harv`, `B_harv`, `loss`, `sweetness`, `comments`) ";
            $sql .= " VALUES ({$values})";

            //echo $sql;

            $result_id = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
            if($result_id == false){
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            $sql = "UPDATE toguchi_harv SET sdate=?, a_harv=?, b_harv=?,
            loss=?,sweetness=?,comments=? WHERE hid=?";
            if($stmt == mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isssiiiis", $param_hid,$param_sdate,$param_block, $param_vid,$param_a_harv,$param_b_harv,$param_loss,
                    $param_sweetness,$param_s_and_c);
        //set parameters
                $param_hid = $hid;
                $param_sdate = $row['jdate'];
                $param_block = $row['block'];
                $param_vid = $vid;
                $param_a_harv = $row['a_harv'];
                $param_b_harv = $row['b_harv'];
                $param_loss = $row['loss'];
                $param_sweetness = $sweetness;
                $param_s_and_c = $s_and_c;
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                    echo "Updated";
                    exit();
                } else{
                    echo "Something went wrong.";
                }
            }
            mysqli_close($link);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

The free mysql data base
Server: sql12.freemysqlhosting.net
Name: sql12238577
Username: sql12238577
Password: L8aEhbgPNP
Port number: 3306

And this is the include db2.inc

```
function connect_mysql(&$link, &$db){

global $link;

    $link = mysqli_connect('sql12.freemysqlhosting.net', 'sql12238577', 
'L8aEhbgPNP');
    if(!$link){
        print "MySQL connection failed!";
        exit();
    }

    $db = mysqli_select_db($link,'test_DB');
    if (!$db){
        die('DB connection failed!'.mysql_error());
        exit();
    }

    mysqli_set_charset($link,'utf8');

    return true;
}

?>
```

Sample data is in this link https://tokyonodai-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/45618006_nodai_ac_jp/EaB74JirQUdJn7OAZ86IQPYBlADKBoHWax-x4_-1pf5rkQ?e=X6dIQ7